# How to add Tradingview's Lightweight-charts to React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tradingview-api, react-tsx, lightweight-charts

I tried installing Tradingview's **'lightweight-charts'** for **react ***typescript***** but I can't seem to download the **@types** for this package because it does not show up on `package.json`. Therefore, unable to render my react app.

I have tried installing with **npm** and **yarn** but they both don't work

Can anyone please help me?

Where can I download the types for this package so it works? The **[npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightweight-charts)** says that it supports typescript.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As part of our package, we generate and provide types that can be found [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/lightweight-charts@3.5.0/dist/typings.d.ts) (for instance).

In theory you shouldn't have to do anything to start working with Typescript as it should work out of the box